# What is eager fetching and lazy fetching in geneal?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm a novice in Grails, and I came across the name Eager and lazy fetching. What are they actually? It will be really good, if the answer explains when each of these techniques should be used?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say you have a simple database schema with a Person table and an address table. If you load a person from the database, you have 2 options.:

- Load the address eagerly so that both the person and the address are returned from the database, probably in one round trip. It is loaded immediately regardless of whether it is needed or used.
- Load the address lazily, which means do not load it until it is needed.

This is just one example, there are lots of others, take this example, written in c#, but should be obvious:

```
private ExpensiveObjectToCreate lazy;
private ExpensiveObjectToCreate eager = new ExpensiveObjectToCreate();

public ExpensiveObjectToCreate Lazy
{
    get
    {
        if(lazy == null)
        {
             lazy = new ExpensiveObjectToCreate();
        }
        return lazy;
    }
}
public ExpensiveObjectToCreate Eager
{
    get
    {
        return eager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside: can you leave out the `()` in C# if a method has no parameters?

Comment: @Aside, you can leave out the `()` of a constructor if using the object or collection initializer syntaz, such as `new Foo {Bar = 1};`, otherwise you cannot.